# createUserWithEmailAndPassword. The named parameter 'email' isn't defined

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

[createUserEmailAndPasswordError]

**Error Screenshot**: [image: screenshot]

I am trying to Auth login using firebase and this error comes up. I tried suing this. or type String before it as it was given in quick fix option but didn't work.

**Full error message** - The named parameter 'email' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'email'. dart(undefined_named_parameter)

**Full code** -

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:socialMediaApp/models/user.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //create user obj based on FirebaseUser
  Users _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? Users(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // sign in with email & password

  // register with email & password
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = (await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password));
      User user = userCredential.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // sign out
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of firebase_auth do you use?

Comment: firebase_auth: "^3.1.4" Also try to change with different down and up.